# "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@f868020

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create an flask API that searchs on a elasticsearch database using the terms it received from the url,here:

```
@app.route('/search_nome/<string:word>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_nome(word):
        try:
                import subprocess, json
                #modelo de input: campo_pesquisado|busca
                file = open("filtro_match.json")
                filtro = file.read()
                file.close()
                lista = word.split("|")
                filtro = filtro.replace("$campo",str(lista[0]))
                filtro = filtro.replace("$busca",str(lista[1]))
                #return "Ok"
                file = open("filtro_match_temp.json", "w")
                file.write(filtro)
                file.close()
                resultado = subprocess.check_output('curl -XGET "localhost:9200/pessoas/_search?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @filtro_match_temp.json')
                temp = resultado.decode('utf-8')
                obj = json.loads(temp)                
                return "O resultado é " + str(obj["hits"]["total"]["value"])
        except:
                return "Error"
```

Basically, the code get the terms from the url, write them on a file and then, use this file to make the search, however, everytime that I run the code, i receiver this error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@f868020; line: 1, column: 39]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@f868020; line: 1, column: 39]"
  },
  "status" : 400
```

I have no idea from where this "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte", can someone help me out?

Comment: I forget to post it before,this is the content of the filtro_match.json: { "query": { "match": { "$campo": "$busca" } } }

Comment: So, I make some progress and discovered that the problem seems to be the fact that i am using non utf-8 characters ("Ç", "á","í") in the json file. I still don't know if this is a problem of the elastic reading the json or the a problem with the json format per se. HELP!